# How can I make google map marker grow bigger when the mouseover it?

Tags: google-maps, animation, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

In Google Map API v3, as the title, I only saw 2 types of animation in google map api, but I saw in some places the map marker animate like grow big when mouse over it? How to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use marker's mouseover event handler and `setIcon()` method. You can use [dynamic icons](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/dynamic_icons.html) from google chart api for this purpose, and change the `chld` attribute to make the icon grow:

[image]
http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.5|0|FF8800|15|_|

[image]
http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.6|0|FF8800|15|_|

[image]
http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.7|0|FF8800|15|_|

Don't forget to set proper anchor point! For example:

```
marker.setIcon(new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.65|0|FF8800|15|_|',
    null,
    null,
    new google.maps.Point(11, 43) // this is the proper anchor point for scale 0.65
));
```

Comment: As of 2012, this is deprecated. Anyone knows a modern solution to this?

Comment: If you just click your own link, you'll see. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use your own image as a marker, then make use of the `scaledSize` property for the marker image to make it bigger when the `mouseover` event fires.

I don't know of a way to do this without doing some more complicated stuff like this.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?  +1 if it actually works.. Please let me know

Comment: @mmmshuddup Sorry, I haven't been working on this for a while. As its been more than a year, you may find that the API has changed/improved since then.